# Kernel stopping and restarting when merging two huge databases

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I know this might be quite a general question but I'll try.
I have 3 huge databases (around 5 Million observations each) that I have to merge all together but when I do using

```
db_cpc_id = pd.merge(df_id_appended, df_cpc_appended, how='left', on='docdb_family_id')
```

the kernel stops working. Any suggestion on how to avoid the kernel restarting? Maybe using pd.concat() might solve the issue?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on the exact reason. In the worst case, you will compute all combinations of the first dataframe rows with all that of the second one (2.5e13 combinations). You could be exhausting your memory.

Comment: What is the output of `df_id_appended['docdb_family_id'].value_counts()` and `df_cpc_appended['docdb_family_id'].value_counts()`? (only the `head()` if the output is too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should consider is that merge is memory intensive and that you simply might not have enough RAM to do this operation. Please have a look at Vaex, as this is a fast and easy way to manipulate massive amounts of data. https://vaex.io/. The syntax is not identical but very similar to pandas. In the example below I am assuming you have 5 CSVs that you can load and merge, and then store.

```
import vaex

vaex_df1 = vaex.from_csv(file1,convert=True, chunk_size=5_000)
vaex_df2 = vaex.from_csv(file2,convert=True, chunk_size=5_000)
joined_df = vaex_df1.join(vaex_df2, how='left', on='docdb_family_id')
```

Please check your system resources when running your code to get a better understanding of why your kernel is failing :)

Comment: Actually I have two pandas ataframes to be merged. Can I do it with vaex in any case? (e.g. a convrsion method from pandas to vaex)

Comment: actually vaex raised thiss issue: ContextualVersionConflict: (ipywidgets 7.5.1 (/Users/federiconutarelli/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('ipywidgets<8,>=7.6.0'), {'ipympl', 'ipyleaflet'})

Comment: Hi @NutarelliFederico, check out https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_pandas. There is a `from_pandas` method for vaex that does exactly what you are looking for. How did you install vaex anyways? Did you follow the installation instruction that are provided on the website?

Comment: thank you for the kind reply. Actually, I solved both issues. However, now I am struggling with the option "allow_duplicate=True". I think I wanted an inner join (since I would like the final daaframe to have the number of rows of the database containing more rows). However when I type in db_cpc_id = vaex_id.join(vaex_cpc, how='inner', on='docdb_family_id',allow_duplication=True) the final database has a lot of rows more. Could you please help me on this? Thank you again!

Comment: @NutarelliFederico, but of course! So the challenge here might be that you are joining on non-unique values. If you are joining with non-unique values, it will replicate the rows, for all possible combinations of matches. Could you validate the hypothesis and check `value_counts` for the individual columns that you want to join on? Please note that you also might be joining on missing-values, that could cause this replication. Please check that too, as it can have massive impact on the join. Good Luck!